# Meaning of "went through the floor"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, meaning

Question:

I read this post:
http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/40480/how-much-traffic-is-necessary-to-generate-1000-per-month-in-advertising-revenue

Quote

> I previously had a real estate listings site and was generating around
>   $1500 mth with about 3000 unique users per day. Content was
>   essentially syndicated but as Google changed algorithm the traffic
>   went through the floor.

Now my question: 
The expression "went through the floor", in this context, what does it mean, collapse or explode ?
I suppose collapse, since the floor is at the bottom, but with expressions, one never knows for certain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it means to collapse, or go way down, or whatever. Contrast with "through the roof".

I can't find a reference but I'm pretty sure the expression originated in the financial markets, wherein a seller or regulator would set a [price floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_floor) on a commodity or security, and if the value of said commodity fell below the floor, it was very undervalued and no one would buy it.

Answer (score 3):

*To go through the floor* [means](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/go-through-the-floor) "to fall to very low levels". So, your quote basically says that the traffic decreased dramatically.